# Property grid with combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, grid, propertygrid

I have some store, which is formed data. On panel, it looks how "fieldName" and text field (in depension from invoked form).

For example, on one form is displayed "name document" and field, on another: date of selling and date field. Data is formed dynamically.

**Here is store:**

```
tableTempStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: objectUrlAddress,
    baseParams: {
        'objectID': objectID
    },
    root: 'Fields',
    fields: [{
        name: 'Hint'
    }, {
        name: 'Type',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'Value'
    }, {
        name: 'Index',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'IsRequired',
        type: 'bool'
    }, {
        name: 'Identifier'
    }, {
        name: 'EnumList'
    }, {
        name: 'Directory'
    }, {
        name: 'Data'
    }],
    listeners: {
        load: function (obj, records) {
            Ext.each(records, function (rec) {
                var item = null;
                switch (rec.get('Type')) {
                case 0: // целое
                    item = new Ext.form.NumberField();
                    item.id = rec.get('Identifier');
                    item.fieldLabel = rec.get('Hint');
                    var isRequired = rec.get('IsRequired');
                    item.anchor = '100%';
                    item.allowBlank = !isRequired;
                    item.disabled = editDisabled;
                    item.value = rec.get('Data');
                    break;
                case 1: // вещественное
                    item = new Ext.form.NumberField();
                    item.id = rec.get('Identifier');
                    item.fieldLabel = rec.get('Hint');
                    var isRequired = rec.get('IsRequired');
                    item.anchor = '100%';
                    item.allowBlank = !isRequired;
                    item.allowDecimals = true;
                    item.disabled = editDisabled;
                    item.value = rec.get('Data');
                    break;
                case 5: // SQL-справочник
                    var dataValues = Ext.util.JSON.decode(rec.get('EnumList'));
                    var dataArray = Object.keys(dataValues).map(function (k) {
                        return [k, dataValues[k]]
                    });
                    item = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                        typeAhead: true,
                        width: '100%',
                        triggerAction: 'all',
                        forceSelection: true,
                        editable: false,
                        hiddenName: rec.get('Identifier'),
                        mode: 'local',
                        store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                            fields: [{
                                name: 'myId',
                                type: 'string'
                            }, {
                                name: 'displayText'
                            }],
                            data: dataArray
                        }),
                        valueField: 'myId',
                        displayField: 'displayText',
                        disabled: editDisabled
                    });
                    item.id = '_' + rec.get('Identifier');
                    item.anchor = '100%';
                    item.fieldLabel = rec.get('Hint');
                    var isRequired = rec.get('IsRequired');
                    item.allowBlank = !isRequired;
                    item.value = rec.get('Data');
                    break;
                }
                if (item != null) {
                    templateGrids.add(item);
                    columnsTable = item.__proto__.constructor.xtype;
                    var s = null;
                    else if (rec.get('Type') == 4) {
                        var dataValues = Ext.util.JSON.decode(rec.get('EnumList'));
                        var dataArray = Object.keys(dataValues).map(function (k) {
                            return [k, dataValues[k]]
                        });
                        combo = new Ext.grid.GridEditor(new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                            id: item.id,
                            allowBlank: item.allowBlank,
                            typeAhead: true,
                            lazyRender: true,
                            triggerAction: 'all',
                            forceSelection: true,
                            queryMode: 'local',
                            editable: false,
                            value: item.value,
                            hiddenName: rec.get('Identifier'),
                            mode: 'local',
                            store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                                fields: [{
                                    name: 'myId',
                                    type: 'string'
                                }, {
                                    name: 'displayText',
                                    type: 'string'
                                }],
                                data: dataArray
                            }),
                            valueField: "myId",
                            displayField: "displayText",
                            disabled: editDisabled
                        }));
                    }
                    source[item.fieldLabel] = '';
                    grid.customEditors['Сохранить в'] = combo;

                    grid.getColumnModel().setConfig([{
                        header: "Поле"
                    }, {
                        header: "Значение",
                        dataIndex: '',
                        renderer: Ext.util.Format.comboRenderer(combo)
                    }]);
                    grid.setSource(source);
                };
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**Here's my property grid:**

```
grid = new Ext.grid.PropertyGrid({
    url: objectUrlAddress,
    id: 'propGrid',
    autoFill: true,
    autoHeight: true,
    width: 200,
    store: tableTempStore,
    width: 600,
    style: 'margin:0 auto;margin-top:10px;'
});
```

Problem with combo box. It show `itemValue` instead `fieldValue` on cell, and I don't know how to resolve this problem. How can I do? Thanks in advance.

**For rendering I used function:**

```
Ext.util.Format.comboRenderer = function (combo) {
    return function (value) {
        var record = combo.findRecord(combo.valueField, value);
        return record ? record.get(combo.displayField) : combo.valueNotFoundText;
    }
};
```

But it not worked.

Comment: Make sure `store` of `combobox` is loaded before setting the value.

Comment: What you mean? First, how i understand, is loaded grid, after that store with items (including combobox with store). On site combobox loads needing items, but keyvalue rendering on grid.

Comment: can you post a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) for what you have done so far.

Comment: I can't registered there. Can you give some advices, how i can resolve problem with combobox?

Comment: What @RohitSharma is saying is that the `store` you use inside the column renderer where the editor is a combobox must be loaded before passing through the renderer method.

You previously create a loading mechanism to try to show the text referring to the value of the combobox `store`.

Right @RohitSharma?

Comment: And how i can solution this problem?